# Significance of $$ in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cte

I was recently given this snippet of code that generates an arbitrary document in MongoDB. I've never encountered **$$** in Mongo before and I'm curious about its significance.

All I know is that if I run the code with a single $, then the n no longer appears... Anyone have an explanation?

***What is the significance of $$ in `$$n`***

### Code

```javascript
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    // use $range to generate iterator [1, 2, 3]
    "$addFields": {
      "rg": {
        "$range": [
          1,
          4
        ]
      },
      globalVar: 0.001
    }
  },
  {
    // do the mapping according to logic
    "$addFields": {
      "cte": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$rg",
          "as": "n",
          "in": {
            n: "$$n",
            f1: {
              "$multiply": [
                "$$n",
                20
              ]
            },
            f2: {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  $lt: [
                    {
                      "$multiply": [
                        "$$n",
                        6
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$multiply": [
                        "$globalVar",
                        100
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "then": {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$$n",
                    6
                  ]
                },
                "else": {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$globalVar",
                    100
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // wrangle back to expected form
    "$unwind": "$cte"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$cte"
    }
  }
]);
```

The [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/06pBbkioYWZ)

Comment: See [Variables in Aggregation Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) `$$n` comes from `as: "n",`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> {
>     // do the mapping according to logic
>     "$addFields": {
>         "cte": {
>             "$map": { ...
>                "input": "$rg",
>                "as": "n",
>                "in": {
>                    f1: {
>                        "$multiply": [
>                            "$$n",
>                            20
>                        ]
>                    },
>                    ...
> ```

This is specific to the using the [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) Aggregation Array Operator. `$map` is used to iterate over an *array* field and *transform* each of the array field elements. The `$map` has parameters - `input` which specifies the array field name, `as` specifies the current array element identifier in an iteration, and `in` where each array element is processed in the iteration.

Within the `in`, the current array element is referred using the `$$` prefix - **this is the syntax required**. The `n` is as defined in the `"as": "n"` - where `n` is a user-defined value (it can be anything, e.g., `n`, `element`, `rg_element`, etc.). But, this is referred by prefixing two dollars (`$$`) before the user-defined value - `$$n` (or `$$element`, etc.) when used.

> All I know is that if I run the code with a single $, then the n no
> longer appears... Anyone have an explanation?

That is because the MongoDB query processor assumes that `n` is a field in the document - which is *not* so. So, it has a identify of a "not exists".

**Also, Note:**

The `$$` prefix is also used with other aggregation operators, e.g., `$filter`, `$lookup` and `$let`. In addition, the `$$` prefix appears in [Aggregation System Variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-variables) - `$$ROOT`, `$$CURRENT`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

There are variables in aggregation expressions:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/